# Delete multiple Google Calendar events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I've created a complete system to plan my work appointments.

I have a database with 6000 different appointments. I only need to select a location, appointmentnumber, and date, and my app sends them to my Google Calendar.

A shift in 2 parts adds 2 events in my calendar

Service # /1 and Service #/2 as title.

Now I'm looking for a way to delete both entries on the same date with one click?

Is there maybe a way to put event id's in an array where the title container /1 or /2 and then delete it?

Comment: What have you already tried? If you have some code to show us please share it here

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, without some more context. Knowing it's part of a "complete system" of your own implies that there are probably enablers and hurdles that we can't anticipate. If you can [edit] your question to focus on one or a few specific issues that you're having, you're more likely to get valuable answers.

Comment: My code creates 2 events at the same time, by times in my databes. It creates Event/1 and Event/2  as title of the event. I just wanted to create something to delete both events at the same time, but how can I get only that two events by date and title?